# A faster way to get screenshots of a video with ffmpeg

Tags: performance, ffmpeg, screenshot

I am trying to use ffmpeg to get screenshots of a video at a given rate, which works exactly as I want, except for the fact that it has to process the entire video (which can take a long time) and use a ton of CPU resources just to grab a few frames.

Here is the ffmpeg command that I am using to get the screenshots:

```
ffmpeg -i "$videoName" -vf fps=$enterFPS img%03d.jpg
```

Is there any way to make that faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`select`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) filter instead.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -vf "select=between(t\,10\,20)" -vsync vfr output_image%04d.png
```

This will output all the frames in between 10-20 time interval. You can also refer [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) for more information.