# How to get thumbnail from Video in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player, flutter-packages, video-thumbnails

I am trying to get a thumbnail from Video.

First I tried [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) package and it worked fine. But problem with that is it takes a little time to generate a thumbnail and in meantime I display CircularProgressIndicator. But it is not good to show CircularProgressIndicator from user experience.

Actually I am making Status Saver App where there will be a list of videos that comes from WhatsApp, etc. And there is Also RefreshIndicator soo whenever user pull the screen the page is rebuilt. So, again CircularProgess Indicator will appear and this is not good in experience.

Therefore I use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package twice. One for generating thumbnail in List of Video(here I only initialize video and do play it) and when I click on video It just goes on another page where another [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) is used for playing the video.
I found this workaround.

but when there are more videos(2-3+) then It gives no thumbnail(video picture) and gives the following error.

```
 E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16007): Playback error E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16007): 
 com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error,
```

I found the cause of the error. It was occurring because when there are many video decoder and it reaches the limit of a mobile device(video decoder limit) then this error appears.

Now I don't know what other solution there is.
I never want to use the [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) package because it is extremely annoying.
I have seen many other **Status Saver** app that showing video thumbnails without any delay even when we refresh the page(using RefreshIndicator) they again occur instantly.

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837433/a-faster-way-to-get-screenshots-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg#30838522

Comment: along with https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg